# Windows Docker Containers on AWS ECS - IAM Roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, docker, amazon-ecs, windows-container

According to [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/windows_task_IAM_roles.html), I need to run the following PShell script when running a container so as to get access to AWS IAM Roles:

```
$gateway = (Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_IP4RouteTable | Where { $_.Destination -eq '0.0.0.0' -and $_.Mask -eq '0.0.0.0' } | Sort-Object Metric1 | Select NextHop).NextHop
$ifIndex = (Get-NetAdapter -InterfaceDescription "Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet*" | Sort-Object | Select ifIndex).ifIndex
New-NetRoute -DestinationPrefix 169.254.170.2/32 -InterfaceIndex $ifIndex -NextHop $gateway
```

However it throws an exception:

> Get-WMIObject : The term 'Get-WMIObject' is not recognized as the name
>   of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
>   spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
>   is correct and try again.

Some googling seems to suggest that the cmdlet has been replaced with `Get-CimInstance`, and this does indeed seem to at least progress to the 3rd line in the script, but then:

> New-NetRoute : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'InterfaceIndex'. Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.UInt32".

The value of `$ifIndex` is an array `[7,19]`.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./ ./
RUN dotnet publish project/project.csproj -c Release -r win-x64 -o out

FROM microsoft/nanoserver:sac2016
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/project/out ./
COPY --from=build-env /app/startProject.ps1 ./

ENTRYPOINT ["powershell", ".\\startProject.ps1"]
```

The full contents of startProject.ps1:

```
$gateway = (Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_IP4RouteTable | Where-Object { $_.Destination -eq '0.0.0.0' -and $_.Mask -eq '0.0.0.0' } | Sort-Object Metric1 | Select-Object NextHop).NextHop
$ifIndex = (Get-NetAdapter -InterfaceDescription "Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet*" | Sort-Object | Select-Object ifIndex).ifIndex
New-NetRoute -DestinationPrefix 169.254.170.2/32 -InterfaceIndex $ifIndex -NextHop $gateway

$scriptDir = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
Start-Process "$scriptDir\Project.exe" -Wait
```

---

**EDIT**

Actually it seems I spoke too soon - using `Get-CimInstance` returns an error:

> Get-CimInstance : Invalid class

Which seems to suggest that it can't find `Win32_IP4RouteTable`

Comment: I'm confused how anything relevant to AIM or AWS has any relevance to stuff which is being run inside container itself.

Comment: @GregorySuvalian IAM, not AIM - my container requires access to other AWS tools (SSM in this case)

Comment: For people not very versed in AWS. It tries to access REST endpoint which is exposed on non-routable IP on the VM itself?

Comment: For the issue itself it's because you have more then 1 gateway most likely on your system inside container. Try to execute following and see if you have more then 1 IP address returned `docker run microsoft/nanoserver:sac2016 powershell (Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_IP4RouteTable | Where-Object { $_.Destination -eq '0.0.0.0' -and $_.Mask -eq '0.0.0.0' } | Sort-Object Metric1 | Select-Object NextHop) | select -property NextHop`

Comment: You can replace CIM part with `Get-NetRoute -DestinationPrefix 0.0.0.0/0 | select nexthop`

Comment: And for interface use `$ifindex = Get-NetAdapter | select -expandproperty ifindex`. I'm not sure what is the point of Sort-Object Select-Object etc in sample

Comment: @GregorySuvalian Sorry I was mistaken earlier - the array [7,19] was being returned by the host machine. The container itself does not seem to find any Win32_IP4RouteTable entries. The output of `docker run microsoft/nanoserver:sac2016 powershell Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_IP4RouteTable` is an error `Invalid class`

Comment: Use `Get-NetRoute` instead of `Get-CIMInstace` like I showed above

Comment: Running `docker run microsoft/nanoserver:sac2016 powershell Get-NetRoute -DestinationPrefix 0.0.0.0/0 | select nexthop` returns 6 items, all empty. Running it without the `select` returns one item, not empty... This is confusing. Have I got the syntax wrong? [screenshot of the results](https://imgur.com/a/G8x9PfH)

Comment: It shall return just 1 result. What your Get-NetRoute. see proper syntax below `docker run -it --rm  microsoft/nanoserver:sac2016 powershell {get-netroute -DestinationPrefix 0.0.0.0/0  | select -expandproperty NextHop}`